# Registro de dominio / subdominio

Tags: api, web, dominio

Tengo un sitio web con un dominio como **miweb.com**. Quiero crear un api rest en un subdominio, con lo que usaría también: **api.miweb.com** ¿Es un dominio aparte en cuanto al registro de dominio?

Comment: ¿Alquién puede crear un etiqueta "dominios"?

Comment: @Ociri Ya la he creado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, si tu registras un dominio, puedes crear los subdominios que quieras. Lo único que tienes que hacer, es correr un DNS para tus subdominios (si quieres diferenciar los IP) o configurar tu agente web para filtrar/redirigir tus servicios. La mayoría de proveedores te permiten configurar subdominios en su nameserver. Pregunta al soporte.

Si necesitas tu propio DNS, te recomiendo [djb's tinydns](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns.html), pero deberías leer y **entender** bien el concepto de DNS, o contratar a un asesor. Generalmente tu proveedor te debería prestar asistencia (si es bueno).