# No puedo agregar un sub dominio a centos 7

Tags: linux, apache2, centos, centos7, httpd

necesito agregar un sub dominio a un servidor centos pero por mas que lo intento no se me da... en el navegador me salta el error `No se puede acceder a este sitio No se pudo encontrar la dirección IP del servidor de dominio.midominio.com.py

Segui paso a paso los tutoriales que basicamente son los mismo...

cree mi directorio.. con el comando

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/dominio.midominio.com.py
```

cambie los permisos para evitar problemas con

```
sudo chown -R apache: /var/www/dominio.midominio.com.py
```

Despues cree mi .conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName dominio.midominio.com.py
ServerAlias www.dominio.midominio.com.py
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com ///aca no se que debe ir... asi que le puse un correo que es del dominio en teoria
DocumentRoot /var/www/dominio.midominio.com.py

<Directory /var/www/dominio.midominio.com.py>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/dominio.midominio.com.py-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/dominio.midominio.com.py-access.log combined
```

Probe la sintaxys de mi configuracion

```
sudo apachectl configtest
```

y me salio OK

reinicie mi apache

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

y me sale como se ve en la caputra de pantalla que subi...
[image: asi es como me sale en en navegador]

mire la consola de errores y solo me salio esto con

```
 tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'

Comment: como seria eso? háblame como a un niño que es la primera ves que hago esto

Comment: Encerio no me puedes brindar mas ayuda que esto?

Comment: Estas colocando la configuracion en un servidor dedicado o en tu lcoalhost ?... Si estas en tu localhost bastaria con que edites el /etc/hosts y agregues la IP 127.0.0.1 y el dominio. Caso contrario si estas en un dedicado deberas registrar el subdominio dentro de la zona, vaya, crear un registro tipo A dentro de la Zona de Dominio principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas *"Agregar un registro tipo A al DNS"*, es decir agregar el subdominio al servidor de nombres de tu dominio.

Por lo regular los proveedores de hosting tienen un panel de configuración donde puedes hacer eso fácilmente. En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/47330/registro-de-dominio-subdominio) hay un par de consideraciones.

Comment: error, si esta en localhost basta con que edite el /etc/hosts

Comment: Esta respuesta funciono para mi... Le había solicitado al proveedor de la empresa para la que trabajo y hoy me dieron un retorno y funciono... gracias @Sal